# MySQL -- count(*) on a relational table while selecting multiple values from another table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have two tables, T1 and T2.

T1 contains columns A1, B1, and C1.  A1 is a unique index for T1.

T2 contains columns A1 and awesome_data. A1 is not unique in this table.  This table keeps many rows of "awesome_data" for each A1.  I need a query that returns all the info from T1 and the COUNT of the occurances of A1 in T2.

So if I have this:

```
T1:
row(A1 = 1, B1 = 'monkey', C1 = 'horsies'),
row(A1 = 2, B1 = 'super mario', C1 = 'satan'),
row(A1 = 3, B1 = 'monkey', C1 = 'hello world')

T2:
row(A1 = 2, awesome_data = 'adsfasd22f32'),
row(A1 = 1, awesome_data = '3f23fsf3a3'),
row(A1 = 1, awesome_data = 'f3af3afaa3fa2')
```

I need a query that results in this:

```
enter code here

array(
0 => array('A1'=>1,'B1'=>'monkey','C1'=>'horsies','T2_count'=>2),
1 => array('A1'=>2,'B1'=>'super mario','C1'=>'satan','T2_count'=>1),
2 => array('A1'=>3,'B1'=>'monkey','C1'=>'horsies','T2_count'=>0)
);
```

Any suggestions?  I tried to make this as clear as possible.  I'm not familiar with the proper way to communicate relational table concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    T1.*,
    COUNT(T2.A1) AS `Total`
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.A1 = T2.A1
GROUP BY T1.A1
```

Here is the 

### SQL Fiddle Demo